# How to trim data before set using Ember.set

Tags: ember.js

As a newbie to Ember.

I have an Object that has to be trimmed for white-spaces before updating/assigning with `ember.set`.

I know it can be done with using `this.set(/**/).trim()`. But just `set()` is not supporting `trim()`. And I have been told `this.set()` is not a best way than compared to just `set()`

`set(Object, Key, get(key, value))` is how my syntax is.

Comment: Do you have control over the object to set the value on? Then you could also make a [computed property](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.3/classes/ComputedProperty) with a get/set and having the set doing the trimming if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just trim NewValue before setting:

```
NewValue = get(key, value).trim();
set(Object, Key, NewValue);
```

Or, if you like brevity:

```
set(Object, Key, get(key, value).trim());
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as I get values using `get()`. Sorry, for to update the code. Did it now.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work, you can see `get.trim()` is not a function error in console.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Could you provide some more details on the exact code? So I can look at it.

Comment: @SarathDamaraju what is `get(key, value)`? If trim is not a function, then `get(key, value)` is obviously not a string.